GAS,NotionAPIを使ってnotionのデータベースの情報をもとにdiscordに通知を送る
GAS、notionAPIを使ってnotionのデータベースから日付が一緒のデータに関してdiscordに通知を送るコードを書きました。実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ました。
トークンキーが間違っているかと思い何度も確認したのですが、そうでもないようで、解決のしようがなくなってしまいました。ご助言よろしくお願いいたします。
エラーメッセージ:
Exception: Request failed for https://api.notion.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"object":"error","status":401,"code":"unauthorized","message":"API token is invalid.","request_id":"d35b6024-e1b1-44c3-b1d6-6383632f605e"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
getNotionData   @ コード.gs:34
myFunction  @ コード.gs:11

現状のコード (トークン、ID、webhookurlは消してあります)
// GASのトリガーで一定間隔で実行する関数
// Notion API の認証トークンとデータベースIDをスクリプトプロパティから取得
const NOTION_TOKEN = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('');
const DATABASE_ID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('');

// Discord Webhook URL
const DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('');

function myFunction() {
  // Notion APIからデータベースの情報を取得
  const notionData = getNotionData(DATABASE_ID, NOTION_TOKEN);

  // 本日の日付のレコードを抽出
  const todayRecords = getTodayRecords(notionData);

  // Discord に通知
  if (todayRecords.length > 0) {
    sendToDiscord(todayRecords);
  }
}

function getNotionData(databaseId, token) {
  const url = `https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/`+ databaseId +`/query`;
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer`+ token,
      'Notion-Version': '2022-06-28'
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({})
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}

function getTodayRecords(notionData) {
  const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  return notionData.results.filter(record => {
    const date = record.properties.Date.date.start;
    return date === today;
  });
}

function sendToDiscord(records) {
  records.forEach(record => {
    const message = {
      content: `New record added to Notion database on ${record.properties.Date.date.start}:\n${record.properties.Name.title[0].plain_text}`
    };
    const options = {
      method: 'post',
      payload: JSON.stringify(message),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL, options);
  });
}


API token is invalidのエラーメッセージから、表示されているスクリプトを見ますと、'Authorization': `Bearer`+ token,の部分で、もしもtokenの最初にスペースがない場合は、これがエラーの原因かもしれません。そこで、'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,のようにスペースを入れて再度テストをしてみてください。databaseIdとtokenが有効な場合は少なくとも現在のエラーメッセージは解消されると思われます。修正箇所の推測が正しいかどうか不明だったため、コメントとして回答させていただきました。

すでにコメントが付いていますので
'Authorization': `Bearer`+ token,

を
'Authorization': `Bearer `+ token,

に修正してもなお期待どおりに動作しない場合、

トークン、ID、webhookurlは消してあります

との記載がありますが、
プロパティサービスを利用しているので
コードには書き込む必要がないと思いますが、
消してあるということは、
次の3行の引用符の中に直接トークン等を記入していますか？
仮にそうであれば、GASでのプロパティサービスの利用方法を
ご確認ください
const NOTION_TOKEN = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('');
const DATABASE_ID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('');
const DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('');

